# Grouped layer control in Leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet

There is a plug-in for Leaflet JS that allows to group the layers in the layer control. https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol

This plug-in does not seem to exist for Leaflet R but I found this post saying that there is a way to use arbitraty Leaflet JS plug-in in Leaflet R.
https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92

I tried to apply this method to the Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol plug-in but did not succeed. Do you have any idea how I can possibly use this plug-in or any other way to group my layers in the layercontrol generated by Leaflet R? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You definitely can do layer control in leafletR. If you version does not have it, then you need to update, probably from the most recent GITHUB version.

I am working on a map right now that has layer controls, see the photograph. Here is the code that makes it happen. As you can see each of the `addPolygons` has a `group = " A Name"` This is where you identify the layers in the check boxes on my image.

```
map<-leaflet()%>%
addTiles()%>%
addPolygons(data = plotMerge,
            fillColor = ~pal(plotMerge$incomePerCapita),
            color = "#000000", #this is an outline color
            fillOpacity = 0.8,
            group="Tract",
            weight = 0.2,
            popup=popup)%>%
addPolygons(data = countyPoly,
            fillColor = "transparent",
            color = "#000000", #this is an outline color
            fillOpacity = 0.8,
            group="County",
            popup=countyPoly@data$NAME,
            weight = 2)%>%
addPolygons(data = townPoly,
            fillColor = "transparent",
            color = "#000000", #this is an outline color
            fillOpacity = 0.8,
            group="Town",
            weight = .8,
            popup=townPoly@data$TOWN)%>%
addPolygons(data = rphnPoly,
            fillColor = "transparent",
            color = "#000000", #this is an outline color
            fillOpacity = 0.8,
            group="Public Health Region",
            weight = .8,
            popup=rphnPoly@data$PHN)%>%
addLegend(pal = pal,
          values  = plotMerge$incomePerCapita,
          position = "bottomright",
          title = "State-wide Income Percentiles",
          labFormat = labelFormat(digits=1))%>%
addLayersControl(
          overlayGroups =c("County", "Town", "Public Health Region", "Tract"),
          options = layersControlOptions(collapsed=FALSE)
          )
saveWidget(map, file="map1.html", selfcontained=FALSE)
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image: ACS Social Vulnerability Index Made on R & LEaflet]

You can also add other controls check it out here:

[Leaflet R Hidden Layers](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to put multiple layers into one same category and to be able to display the name of that category on the legend as shown in this page : https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol

Comment: This is the same thing, I have never used the radio button on overlays, only on base layers. But you can create a group that was county and assign it to 1, 2, 3 ,4 layers of lines, polygons or markers and they would all be controlled by a single check box.  It is like creating a class or id in html to control it with css or javascript. That box is not the legend, it is the selection tool. What goes into the legend it configured by how you program the legend code to look at data, it might take work outside of leaflet to make the information that goes into the legend reflect your groups.

Comment: CYC, can you post the code you wrote to try the Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol plug-in?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I didn't find a good answer elsewhere - this may help others in the future.

Here is a reprex with comments that explains the code:

```
#load library
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

#load data
data("quakes")

#map all points
# quakes %>% 
#   leaflet() %>% 
#   addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>% 
#   addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, radius = 1)

#create a grouping variable -- this can be whatever you want to filter by 
quakes <- quakes %>% 
  mutate(groups = case_when(
    stations < 30 ~ 1,
    stations < 50 ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ 3
  ))


#function to plot a map with layer selection 
map_layers <- function() {

  #number of groups
  k <- n_distinct(quakes$groups)

  #base map
  map <- leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)

  #loop through all groups and add a layer one at a time
  for (i in 1:k) {
    map <- map %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(
        data = quakes %>% filter(groups == i), group = as.character(i),
        lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, radius = 1
      )
  }

  #create layer control
  map %>% 
    addLayersControl(
      overlayGroups = c(1:k),
      options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>% 
    hideGroup(as.character(c(2:k))) #hide all groups except the 1st one

}

#plot the map
map_layers()
```